# How to create a new variable using the Mutate function?

Tags: r

I need to add to my data a new variable, but I would like to do it using the mutate function. How can I do it? ISLR library

Create a new variable called "HighVol" that has the classes "yes" and "no"
to indicate whether the location sold 10,000 units or more in the past year.
How many stores produced a high volume?

```
Example below. 
 carseats.df$HighVol <- factor(carseats.df$HighVol,
                 levels = c(0,1),
                 labels = c("No", "Yes"))
```

Answer (score 0):

You are going to include the entire data frame if you use `mutate`. You'll want to whole data frame if the assignment of yes or no is conditionally based on sales.

```
library(tidyverse)

# create carseats.df
set.seed(39582) # make it repeatable
carseats.df <- data.frame(sales = rnorm(100, 10000, 505))

# now create conditional variable
carseats.df <- carseats.df %>% 
  mutate(HighVol = ifelse(sales > 10000,  # true or false
                          "yes",   # result if true
                          "no") %>% 
           as.factor()) # result if false

head(carseats.df)
#       sales HighVol
# 1  9992.190     yes
# 2 10077.482      no
# 3  9507.145     yes
# 4 10780.788      no
# 5 10433.133      no
# 6 10907.665      no
```

It looks like you're fairly new to SO; welcome to the community! If you want great answers quickly, it's best to make your question reproducible. This includes sample data like the output from `dput(head(dataObject)))` and any libraries you are using. Check it out: [making R reproducible questions](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5963269).

The reason you haven't seen any help is most likely due to the lag of meaningful tags. You only have the tag `tree` which isn't meaningful. At a minimum, you would want to include a tag for the programming language: `r`. You could also add things like `mutate` or the library it's derived from, `dplyr`.

Comment: Thank you, Kat,  I tried o use a different vocabulary, but I keep getting the message that did not let my question go through. I did not know what I was doing wrong.

Comment: Thank you for answering my questions. I am very new to learning the R language and using the community. I will take your advice.